# What's the meaning of "we're doing a good job with sb/sth"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

It's from a piece of news about the trade war. Trump said that they're doing a very good job with China". I know "do a good job" means "do something well". But I feel quite confused about it followed with "with sb/sth". Does it mean "cooperate well with sb" or "treat sb well" or "both sides do something well"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There **with** means "in respect to", or "regarding".

You have to allow context to guide you in situations where a word has multiple meanings.  Do we really "cooperate" with an adversary? The context is a trade war.

> You did a great job with that playground bully.  It is good to intercede  as you did.